# React listen to child's state from parent

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

Damn, two days, two noob questions, sorry guys.

Yesterday, I spent the whole afternoon reading the docs but my fart-ey brain cannot process how to use react hooks to pass data from a child to a parent.

I want to create a button on my parent that can listen to his child's state to check on it and change the background color depending on its value.

Thing is, the child component is mapping some stuff so I cannot create a button (otherwhise it would be rendered multiple times and not only once like I want).

I've thought about moving all the data to my parent component but I cannot understand how since I'm fairly new to React and it's been only two months of learning how to code for me basically.

I will now provide the code for the parent and the child component.

The parent :

```
import React from "react";
import Quizz from "./components/Quizz";

export default function App() {
  const [quizz, setQuizz] = React.useState([]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    async function getData() {
      const res = await fetch(
        "https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=5&category=27&type=multiple"
      );
      const data = await res.json();
      setQuizz(data.results)
    }
    getData();
  }, []);

  function checkOnChild(){ /* <== the function I'd like to use to check on my Quizz component's "activeAnswer" state */
      console.log(quizz);
  }
  
    const cards = quizz.map((item, key) => {
    return <Quizz {...item} key={key}/>;
  });
  return (
    <div>
      {cards}
      <button onClick={checkOnChild}>Check answers</button> /* <== the button that will use the function */
    </div>
  );
}
```

and the child :

```
import React from "react";
import { useRef } from "react";

export default function Quizz(props) {

  const [activeAnswer, setActiveAnswer] = React.useState('');/* <== the state I'd like to check on from my parent component */

  function toggle(answer) {
    setActiveAnswer(answer);
  }

  function shuffleArray(array) {
    for (let i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
      let j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
      let temp = array[i];
      array[i] = array[j];
      array[j] = temp;
    }
    return array;
  }

  let answers = props.incorrect_answers;

  const ref = useRef(false);
  if (!ref.current) {
    answers.push(props.correct_answer);

    shuffleArray(answers);
    ref.current = true;
  }

  const answerDiv = answers.map((answer, key) => (
    <div key={key} className="individuals" onClick={()=> toggle(answer)} 
    style={{background: answer == activeAnswer ? "#D6DBF5" : "transparent" }}>
    {answer}
    </div>
  ));

  console.log(answers);
  console.log(activeAnswer);
  console.log(props.correct_answer);

  return (
    <div className="questions">
      <div>
        <h2>{props.question}</h2>
      </div>
      <div className="individuals__container">{answerDiv}</div>
      <hr />
      
    </div>
   
  );
}
```

I'm really sorry If it seems dumb or if I'm making forbidden things lmao, but thanks in advance for your help guys!

Comment: I don't 100% understand your question and desired outcome, but it seems to me that you need to think about lifting the state up to the highest level where it needs to be accessed and then passing it as props to the children that also need it. Whilst this in mind, I'm pretty confident you will solve this one yourself! You can read more about this here: https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Comment: You question is unclear. Do you need to display data through card component?

Comment: @André Krosby :I've tried lift the state to my App component but the thing is : my Quizz component is mapped so to access something like "props.question" I would have to do "quizz[0].question" to render the first div out of 5. Same would go to the "answers" array (which is also mapped inside the Quizz component to render the 4 answers in individual divs). Now If I could lift the activeAnswer state into the App component that would be a great solution but I just can't figure out how at the moment. But thanks for believing in me, I'll try my best to do it!

Comment: @ Rahul : Kinda, since the cards inside the App component is used to map the Quizz component 5 times and the cards inside the Quizz component is used to map the array of answers (which displays the 4 divs I'm using to render the 4 answers of the array "answers"). I know I'm doing something wrong and I'm sorry for being unclear ^^'

Comment: So you only want one button to check the answers to the 5 quiz questions in your app, am I getting that right? And when you click an answer, that question should be "focused"?

Comment: @ André Krosby : Yeah that's right, I want this single button to check which one of my answers is focused (the focused state is activeAnswer inside my Quizz component). But since it's in my Quizz component I cannot use this single button in my App component to check on it. Now If I could return a single button directly into my Quizz component that would be way easier haha. But since I mapped it, it would be rendered 5 times. Dayumn I didn't think it would be this hard but seems like I spaghetti codded this project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you a bit further I think.

```
export default function App() {
  const [quizData, setQuizData] = useState([])
  const [quizState, setQuizState] = useState({})

  useEffect(() => {
    async function getData() {
      const res = await fetch('https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=5&category=27&type=multiple')
      const data = await res.json()
      const results = data.results

      setQuizData(results)
      setQuizState(results.reduce((acc, curr) => ({ ...acc, [curr.question]: '' }), {}))
    }
    getData()
  }, [])

  function checkOnChild() {
    console.log(quizState)
  }

  const cards = quizData.map((item) => {
    return <Quizz {...item} key={item.question} quizState={quizState} setQuizState={setQuizState} />
  })

  return (
    <div>
      {cards}
      <button onClick={checkOnChild}>Check answers</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

```
export default function Quizz(props) {
  function handleOnClick(answer) {
    props.setQuizState(prevState => ({
      ...prevState,
      [props.question]: answer,
    }))
  }

  const answers = useMemo(() => {
    const arr = [...props.incorrect_answers, props.correct_answer]
    return shuffleArray(arr)
  }, [props.incorrect_answers, props.correct_answer])

  const answerDiv = answers.map((answer) => (
    <div
      className="individuals"
      key={answer}
      onClick={() => handleOnClick(answer)}
      style={{ background: answer == props.quizState[props.question] ? '#D6DBF5' : 'transparent' }}
    >
      {answer}
    </div>
  ))

  return (
    <div className="questions">
      <div>
        <h2>{props.question}</h2>
      </div>
      <div className="individuals__container">{answerDiv}</div>
      <hr />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's kinda working except now I can only get one active selected div and it shuffles everytime I click but it's better than it was before I guess, now I got some clues on how to make it work! Thanks for your precious time mate!

Comment: Update : No more shuffle on each click, now I just have to find how to select one answer on each div and not only one answer for all the divs. Thanks again, now I can make progress x)

Comment: After playing with the code and reading the docs for almost 5 hours, I can't seem to find any solution on how to select 1 answer for each of the 5 questions. I can only select 1 answer for the whole thing. 
I tried to put the state in the child component to see if it worked and yes, it did. But back the old problem, I cannot check its value with the parent.
Maybe I'm just too new to coding and I should put this project aside for a little while. That being said, thanks again for all the help, have a nice rest of your day!

Comment: @Sepulcherz see my updated answer!

Comment: YOU ARE MY HERO :o

Thanks man, now it's all working as I wanted ! I'm gonna learn from your code, you can be sure of it! I didn't know about useMemo, seems to be what I needed. Plus, your code is way lighter than my old code! Thanks again for saving me from this headache!
Have a good day :D

Comment: Glad to hear it working, happy to help!